# Will I get more dyno hours if I transfer an app to another account on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, dyno

One of my app on Heroku has used up 550 free dynamo hours. And I am not able to add credit card to get 450 more hours. So, can I get more dyno hours by transferring the app to another account?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean.

[Your existing account will not get back the hours this app consumed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool):

> Used free dyno hours arenon-transferable. If you transfer an application which has used hours to a different account, the portion you used while the app was on your account will remain until it resets the following month.

If you are asking whether the new account will be able to run the transferred app on a new set of free hours, I believe the answer is yes.

Be careful with this, though. If I were Heroku I'd have systems in place to detect "app juggling". It is probably easier to just wait for your hours to reset.